# ASP.NET_SessionId cookie on iOS & Chrome

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies

I am using the HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession to decide on what page to show when my MVC4 application launches.

This works great on desktop, iOS safari.

However on iOS Chrome, every time I close the browser (actually close tabs and close the application from the task manager) and relaunch it the IsNewSession is always false.

I am guessing it uses the session cookie ASP.NET_SessionId to track this as there is a new cookie value when I close my desktop or safari.

However on iOS Chrome, when I close and relaunch the cookie has the old value - which I am guessing is the root of the issue.

So why does iOS/Chrome not clear my ASP.NET_SessionId cookie even though it should be a Session cookie and deleted when the browser is closed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because of a design feature of many modern mobile operating systems whereby apps don't really close when you might think.

With desktop applications you have a lot more [screen real estate](http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/screen-real-estate/) and so it's easier to manage windows and multitask. So closing applications feels natural and necessary when you're done with it.

With mobile applications, however, there is more of a focus on the user being able to open and switch between applications seemlessly and so the concept of closing or minimising apps is abstracted away and taken care of by the operating system.

This means that when you close Chrome, it's not really closing (and may not close at all before you enter the app again). Therefore the session is never cleared.

If you [force close](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5137) the app then your function will work as expected.

There's no elegant work-around that I can think of for your problem. One idea is to store the time of last activity for the user and if it's greater than, for example, 5 minutes, then you can show them your startup page.

Comment: Additional: If you're already force-closing the app as instructed by Apple, then this answer probably doesn't explain anything and I don't know what the answer is.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I am force closing the app which makes things a little more confusing.  Having the time of last visit might be something we can work with, I will have to put it to the powers who be.